# Push notifications to various devices through a common code

Tags: java, ios, jms, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement which is that I have to push the messages to various users who are using android or iphone devices.I know the individual process to send the push notification to android or iphone application.

Now my work is that I need to do the server side implementation in java so that messages can be sent to android and iphone devices.The number of users using the andrioid and iphone devices is large say 10000 people.

So to implement this requirement What should be the approach.
What should be my approach to send the multicast messages to android and iphone devices?
I am thinking of using the threads say there are 10000 users and I have made 10 threads so each thread out of 10 thread will handle push notifications for 1000(=10000/10) users.

Any other suugestion..

Should I use JMS and if yes then what should be the approach using JMS.

Please suggest me its very much urgent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

What I am currently doing is:

1. receive input that would want to send a push notification
2. send that to an ActiveMQ queue
3. a listener receives that message then has another class build out the message to send to the user
4. then send new message based on step 3 to another ActiveMQ queue
5. a listener receives that message then has another class fire out message to users device based on device type

The reason I went this route was steps 1,3,5 could have their `concurrency` changed in the `applicationContext.xml`.

[image: Example Pic]

Comment: Thanks for you approach.Could you please explain about the ActiveMQ queue.Is it the same as the concept of Java messaging service?Here can we use the message as Json string?I am new to the JMS so please explain

Comment: in case of web app, how about sending notification based on user activity directly from browser to activemq rather than sending to some other middleware because mqtt is made for direct connection

Answer (score 0):

If you have the budget and it is urgent checkout http://urbanairship.com/

I've used it and it's great.

Comment: I am asking about the architecture for the mentioned requirement for which I need to develop the code

Comment: For Urban Airship you can use any web technology you like, you post JSON requests to Urban Airship and it does push to all the platforms for you. Alternatively they have a web interface you can send all your push notifications from, so all you need to do then is setup your apps to subscribe for the notifications.